# Is there a way to hold thread for a condition in Javascript.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

**Scenario:**
I am developing a shopping cart page with react and javascript . i have 2 sections in it , shipping address and billing address .

I am storing both the addresses in the redux after user exits from these sections . After this when user clicks on place order , i need to call an API to validate both the addresses and then if those are valid i have to finally call the Order API.

I tried multiple approaches and am facing different challenges in them:

**Approach 1:**
Whenever user clicks on the order button , i am calling validation API , but i can not store there result in the redux because , as soon as the api is called i have to check for the result and then based on the result either call the different component or another api.
As redux state will set in async manner , which will not allow me to check for the condition soon after setting it.
So in this approach am stuck at this point .?

**Approach 2**:
To successfully have the validation responses stored in redux , i tried to make the validation api call as soon as user tabs out of the address fields and then store them into redux . so that by the time user comes to place order we have the result in redux state , but if the validation api call is taking some time and within this time user clicks on order , then it will accept the order call and calls this api , which i do not want to happen.
So to avoid this i tried to maintain a counter in redux state as activeCalls and every time an api call is in progress counter increases and after completion counter decreases.
But when user clicks on order , i want to check if activeCalls count is 0 then call order api else wait for other calls to get completed and then call order api. So how can i make the api call wait until that counter turns 0.?

Comment: No need to "hold" the thread, just use the promise API and `async`/`await` to act when a call finishes.

Comment: @VLAZ, i can use promise API in the 1st approach but there i will not get the state values just after setting it as i explained.

Comment: This happens on the front-end, so the user has full control over all code that is executed there. How do you validate in the backend that address validation has actually been performed before the Order API is called? Personally I would let the API do both the validation and the processing of the order. That guarantees that the addresses are validated first, and resolves the issue you are facing now as well.

Comment: @Ivar, i have two different end points , address validation is some open source api and order is the api i have written , i do not wish to merge both.

Comment: @shubham That is up to you. But if there is no validation on your Order API itself then a malicious user can simply alter the code on the frontend to bypass this validation.